# Querying from Android to Google App Engine via Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to make a Query to my Datastorage on Google App Engine. My app makes this:

```
      String parametroDate = "_createdAt";
      CloudQuery cq1 = new CloudQuery("Clip");
      cq1.setScope(Scope.PAST);
      Filter userFilter = Filter.eq("clip_user", main.user.getUsername().toLowerCase()); // This filter on its own works fine

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get my time
      Date date = new Date();
      date.setMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis());
      cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0); // And set to 00:00:00
      cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      date.setMillis(cal.getTimeInMillis());
      Filter userMayorqueHoy = Filter.ge(parametroDate, date);  // Greather than today at 00:00:00
      cq1.setFilter(Filter.and(userFilter, userMayorqueHoy));
```

The `Date` class is `org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors.Date` got from AppEngine's library. I've also tried with `java.sql.Date`. In both cases, the result is the same:

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400
>   Bad Request
>
> {
>
> "code": 400,
>
> "errors": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "domain": "global",
>
>   "message": "_createdAt: java.util.LinkedHashMap is not a supported property type.",
>
>   "reason": "badRequest"
>
> }
> ```
>
> ],
>
> "message": "_createdAt: java.util.LinkedHashMap is not a supported
>   property type."
>
> }

In my DataStore it's a Date type.

This is the query:

```
{filterDto={operator=AND, subfilters=[{operator=EQ, values=[clip_user, franexp]}, {operator=GE, values=[_createdAt, org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors.Date@43367c00]}]}, kindName=Clip, scope=PAST}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Date data type is not supported in Datastore used by Mobile Backend Starter. Use **DateTime** from this package *com.google.api.client.util.DateTime* instead. You can create new instance of DateTime by passing to its constructor your Date object:

```
new DateTime(date);
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. I had also experienced the same thing and you use DateTime passing in the date as a param.